# Roslyn .net compiler - Solution Startup projects

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

How to find the solution startup projects.
The solution is loaded in to MsBuildWorkspace and compiled successfully.
Project dependency graph does not have a method to find this information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no roslyn api exposing this information as it is purely a Visual Studio debugger concept.